# Need help debugging JavaScript in IE8

Tags: javascript

Alright, [I'm at a loss here](http://sunnyslope.heroku.com)

I'm getting errors for any locally hosted js files that all point to the doctype as the location.  It doesn't matter what local js file I include, they all raise an error.  No javascript works on the site in IE.

Any and all help greatly appreciated!  Happy to answer any questions to give you more info, I'm just not sure what you'd be looking for as js is not one of my greater skills...

Comment: It would be better if you post code here. If those link's content's were to change or become dead, this question will make no sense for future readers.

Comment: yeah, i understand, but given the nature of the question (ANY locally hosted js files throw an error), I'm not even sure what to include...

Comment: It might have something to do with the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't think this page works on any browser:

http://sunnyslope.heroku.com/javascripts/jquery.fancybox.pack.js
http://sunnyslope.heroku.com/javascripts/application.js

Those two files are served as HTML, so that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: goodness gracious, looks like a server setup issue then.  Sigh...coding after midnight....

Comment: how's about we all just pretend this never happened, eh?  Thanks!

Comment: /cashes the 15 reputation/ ... deal! :)